# BigQuery: very slow join on date and _table_suffix

Tags: google-bigquery, data-partitioning

In my query I wish to get data from a partitioned table, where each user requires a different partition depending on a date particular to the user. This requires me to join on user and date = partition. This join is very, very slow. Taking 12 minutes or so to run!

The basic structure of the query is below:

```sql
SELECT
 t1.user_id
 ,t1.date
 ,t2.some_field
FROM `t1`   AS t1
JOIN `t2_*` AS t2
 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
 AND t2._table_suffix = FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", t1.date)
```

How can I get the same result quicker?

Comment: First, how many partitioned tables do you have and how big are they?

Comment: lots of partitions (1000s), each with large amounts of data (event level data, ie user log on)...

Comment: Ok. Then, I will try to find a public dataset to reproduce your case and find a better syntax to your query.

Comment: I queried some public datasets, so far I was not able to reproduce your issue but when the dataset is filtered before you join, the query becomes faster. Thus, you could try to do so **<your query> JOIN (SELECT t2.some_field FROM ` t2_* ` where  t2._table_suffix = FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", t1.date)**. Can you try that and check if it is better?

Comment: I don't understand your query... please could you send me the full version?

Comment: Here it is : select t1.origin as or1, t2.origin
from ` chrome-ux-report.country_ck.201712 ` t1 join (select * from ` chrome-ux-report.country_cl.* ` where origin = ' https://m.facebook.com ') t2 on t1.origin = t2.origin;

Comment: Thanks, but that does not do the job as it does not solve the join between date and table_suffix

Comment: It should lower your time in at least 10% according to the tests I have made. It does that because you filter the t2 data before joining the tables. I have posted as a model for the syntax you could use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206594/discussion-between-alexandre-moraes-and-johnny-v).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things that sped this query up (from 12 mins to 1 min):

1. Pre filtering the t2 table to the partitions relevant to the join with t1
2. Adding a date field to the CTE of t2 to make the join with t1 quicker

This looks like so:

```sql
WITH t1_dates AS (
 SELECT
 MIN(date) min_date
 ,MAX(date max_date
 FROM
 `t1`
)

, t2_v2 AS (
 SELECT
 user_id
 ,some_field
 ,PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", t2._table_suffix) date

 from t2_*
 ,t1_dates

 where _table_suffix BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",t1_dates.min_date) 
                         AND FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",t1_dates.max_date) 
)

SELECT
 t1.user_id
 ,t1.date
 ,t2.some_field
FROM `t1`   AS t1
JOIN t2_v2 AS t2
 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
 AND t2.date = t1.date
```